# How to Get the BitMap from a NetworkImageView

Tags: android, networkimageview

I have a NetworkImageView where I download images from a server. However, the requirement is to have the ability to rotate the image after downloading the image. I have a rotate image function but I need to get the Bitmap associated to the NetworkImageView in order for me to rotate the bitmap. How can I access the BitMap from a NetworkImageView?

Comment: I hope you know that it is not necessary to use NetworkImageView, you can request a Bitmap directly and set it to an ImageView. It will save you a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method to get bitmap of any view.

`Bitmap bitmap = viewToBitmap(mImageView);`

`Bitmap bitmap = viewToBitmap(mLinearlayout);`

`Bitmap bitmap = viewToBitmap(mRelativelayout);`

```
 public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

**UPDATE**

Create a volley image request.
After the image has been loaded and set inside the **NetworkImageView** this code will work. Else it will return a Null pointer since there is no view/image inside the **NetworkImageView**

```
mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.networkImage);
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mNetworkImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

There is another way to use Volley and obtain the Bitmap.

`Create an ImageRequest`

`inside the onResponse(), obtain the Bitmap and set it to your ImageView (Not NetworkImageView). I had mentioned this method in the comments above.`

Comment: This is throwing null for (BitmapDrawable) mNetworkImageView.getDrawable().

Comment: Go through the Edit now and try. It will work now. You probably didn't wait for the image to load in the first place.